# Javascript Hangman - Replace Character In String

Tags: javascript

I've seen similar questions asked on Stack Overflow regarding this topic, but I haven't seen anything specific that would help me. My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to replace a dash in `hiddenWord` with a correctly guessed letter while still retaining the dashes for un-guessed letters. Here is what I have so far and I'm not even sure if it's on the right track.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Declaration of Variables 
var wordPool= ["Alf", "MarriedWithChildren", "Cheers", "MASH", "CharlesInCharge", "FmailyTies", "KnightRider", "MagnumPI", "MiamiVice"];
var lives = 6;
var myLetter;
var letter;
var wordChoice;
var hiddenWord;
var i;
var enter;

// Selects word randomly from wordPool[]. Then replaces the letters with "- ".

function selectedWord() {

var number = Math.round(Math.random() * (wordPool.length - 1));

wordChoice = wordPool[number];

for(i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++){
    hiddenWord = wordChoice.replace(/./g,"- ");
}
console.log(hiddenWord);
}

// Gives myLetter a value of key pressed. If key is "Enter" selectedWord() initiates 

document.onkeyup = function(event) {

var myLetter = event.key;
    if(myLetter === "Enter"){
        selectedWord();
    }
    console.log(myLetter);
}

</script>
```

I have seen some stuff with jQuery and PHP but I have to do it in javascript for class. Any help would be appreciated and if this has been addressed before please let me know.

Comment: You can probably figure out the code yourself, but the algorithm I would employ is simply walk the wordChoice and find all the indexes of that letter. Then use that index to replace the dash in hiddenWord

Comment: Make sure that when you compare letters, they are in the same case, so when you type `m` you guess both `M` and `m` in `MagnumPI`.

Comment: I don't think jQuery will help you at all with basic string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check each character at the word string, compare it with the chosen character and replace it, if it is the same character.

I changed your code a bit to reflect what you are looking for.
Also make sure to lowercase all characters to make it easier for the player.

```
// Declaration of Variables 
var wordPool= ["Alf", "MarriedWithChildren", "Cheers", "MASH", "CharlesInCharge", "FmailyTies", "KnightRider", "MagnumPI", "MiamiVice"];
var lives = 6;
var myLetter;
var letter;
var wordChoice;
var hiddenWord;
var i;
var enter;

// Change character to selected one
function checkCharacter(n) {
  for(i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++){
    console.log(wordChoice[i].toLowerCase() + "==" + n);
    if(wordChoice[i].toLowerCase() == n.toLowerCase()){
      hiddenWord = setCharAt(hiddenWord,i,n);
    }
  }
  console.log("[" + hiddenWord + "]");
}

function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}

// Selects word randomly from wordPool[]. Then replaces the letters with "- ".

function selectedWord() {
  var number = Math.round(Math.random() * (wordPool.length - 1));
  wordChoice = wordPool[number];
  hiddenWord = wordChoice.replace(/./gi,"-");
  console.log(wordChoice + "[" + hiddenWord + "]");
}

// Gives myLetter a value of key pressed. If key is "Enter" selectedWord() initiates 

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var myLetter = event.key;
    if(myLetter === "Enter"){
        if(lives == 0){
           selectedWord();
           lives = 6;
         }else{
           lives--;
         }
    }
    console.log(myLetter);
    checkCharacter(myLetter);
}

//Select a random word at start
selectedWord();
```

I made a JSfiddle that is working and playable:
[Check it out here...](https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/aag79ftu/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I could not for the life of me figure out how to check the letter and replace it. I'm in an accelerated program so Javascript was a one week crash course.

Comment: No problem, i edited the solution with a working JSFiddle, just follow the link. Goodluck with you course!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`hiddenWord += "- "`
Instead of replace

Or

`hiddenWord += wordChoice[i].replace(/./g,"- ");`

Comment: *hiddenWord* is initially undefined, so `hiddenWord +=` will throw an error. But that's not the OP's issue.

Comment: Oh my bad. I see. The question is to implement the main function of the game which is to display the correct letters of the hidden world. My bad. @TRR88 the point is to try it your self and when something doesnt work then you post your problem. It is not our homework it is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
var word = "do this";
var displayWord = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {//build array
    if (word[i] === " ") {
      displayWord.push(" ");
    } else {
      displayWord.push("-");
    }
  }

function update(userGuess) {//update array
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === userGuess) {
      displayWord[i] = userGuess;
    } else {
      displayWord[i] = displayWord[i];
    }
  }
}

//Guess letters
update("h");
update("o");

displayWord = displayWord.join('');//convert to string

alert(displayWord);
```

Check out the pen - https://codepen.io/SkiZer0/pen/VbQKPx?editors=0110

Comment: Thank you for your help!